# R barplot color by column while keeping the dataframe order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar plot in R that will keep the order of my data and that will color the data by a different color.
my data looks like that:

```
row.name  BMP2      type
qaz        4         gf
zaq        3         gf
xsw        5         ds
```

the data is orderd by 'type' col.

Below is the plot I got. I've indicated the parts I wish to color:

[image: bar plot image]

my code:

```
 barplot(height = h$BMP2,
          las=3,                                  
          space=1,                                
          main = chosen_gene                         
  )
```

*a solution using ggplot2 will be appreciated

Comment: There is no column `BMP2`. Do you mean `GLIPR1`?

Comment: yes,sorry (just created several of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be the large number of bars. With base R `barplot` the bars' borders are black and are making the colors invisible. With `ggplot2` a similar effect also happens.

So I will first create a larger dataset.

```
h <- read.table(text = "
row.name  BMP2    type
qaz        4         gf
zaq        3         gf
xsw        5         ds                  
", header = TRUE)

h <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:(700/3), function(i) h[sample(nrow(h)), ]))
h <- h[order(h$type), ]
h$row.name <- paste0(h$row.name, seq_along(h$row.name))
h$BMP2 <- sample(20, nrow(h), TRUE)

dim(h)
#[1] 699   3
```

Now the plots.

Define a vector of colors based of the lengths of the groups of `type`. Then use that vector to assign colors to the bars.

```
l <- lengths(split(h$type, h$type))
col <- rep(seq_along(l), l)

barplot(height = h$BMP2,
        las = 3,                                  
        space = 1,                                
        main = "chosen_gene",
        col = col,
        border = NA
)
```

[image]

As for the `ggplot` graph, first reorder the column `type` of class `"factor"` in order to have the bars plotted by groups.

```
library(ggplot2)

h$row.name <- factor(as.character(h$row.name), levels = h$row.name, labels = h$row.name)

ggplot(h, aes(x = row.name, y = BMP2, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: the first part hasn't worked, all of the bar plot remained dark. in the ggplot2 part i don't want to rearrange by row name since i need the bar to be ordered by type

Comment: What is the return value of `h$type`? As for the `ggplot` part, give me a moment.

Comment: each element in h$type is a factor if that's what you mean

Comment: @sahar Done, see if this is it.

Comment: unfortunately not. the thing is that all the int column are OK i got 1 or 2 according to the type value but it still only appear in black

Comment: @sahar Are you using the data you have posted? it works with me and I cannot see how it can go wrong. If you are using another dataset, can you edit the question with the new dataset?

Comment: the data it self is a medical data and so i cant post it but its the same in the class value..the row names are character the BMP2 and type are factors

Comment: @sahar You have to change the `BMP2` to numeric: `h$BMP2 <- as.numeric(as.character(h$BMP2))`.

Comment: @sahar As for `barplot`, use Dave2e's suggestion `border = NA`. As for `ggplot`, delete `colour = type`, keep just `fill = type`. I will edit the answer with a larger dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a vector `mycols` that would allow you to choose each bar color as you wish. Based on your sample data, if you wanted the first 2 bars to be blue and the last one to be red:

```
myids <- 1:nrow(h)
mycols <- ifelse(myids<=2, "blue", "red")
barplot(height = h$GLIPR1,
        las=3,                                  
        space=1,                                
        main = chosen_gene,
        col=mycols, 
        border = NA  # remove the black hairline around each box
)
```

[image]
Here the color depends on `myid` which is simply the row nomber of `h`, but you can define other conditions as you please.

Comment: your bars might be too small, can you try with the 50 first rows? otherwise, can you please share your code?

Comment: i got 703 rows, 50 rows will be in the same color rather it works or not, i shared my code above and implemented the code you wrote

Comment: With 700 vertical bar, the black borders on the bars is obscuring the colors.  Add "border=NA" to barplot function. (see the edit in the above answer)